# Convert MySQL string into Time

Tags: mysql, date, time

I have a column that is the time stored as for example 0545 (5:45 am) and a date column stored as 20180801.  I want to combine these into one value of 2018/08/01 05:45 am)  I am doing this over an ODBC connection if that makes a difference.  I can use STR_TO_DATE on the date column but I can't figure out the time column.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_to_date()` on the whole thing:

```
select str_to_date(concat(datecol, timecol), '%Y%m%d%h%i')
```